# Handling blank cells while calculating SMA

Tags: excel, vba, union

I'm trying to skip the blank cells from a range so that it does not alter my simple moving average. So I try to start from a range, "copy/paste" the non blank values within a new range called oRng so that I can use the new range to calculate my SMA.

I got a error 5 saying "Argument or procedure call incorrect" on this line

```
Set oRng = Application.Union(oRng, cell)
```

Here is my full code:

```
Function SMA(rng As Range, N As Integer)

    Dim oRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    For Each cell In rng
        If not IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
            Set oRng = Application.Union(oRng, cell)
    Next cell

    SMA = Application.Average(oRng.Resize(N, 1))

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Try, `If oRng Is Nothing Then`, `Set oRng = cell`, `Else`, `Set oRng = Application.Union(oRng, cell)`, `End If`.

Comment: `oRng.Resize(N, 1)` won't work with a non-continous range. You can only resize continous ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oRng.Resize(N, 1)` won't work with a non-continous range. You can only resize continous ranges. Therfore you need to resize the cells before you collect them in `oRng` using `Union`.

Also after `Dim oRng As Range` the variable `oRng` is `Nothing` and you cannot use `Nothing` in `Union` so you need to test this first and directly `Set oRng = cell.Resize(N, 1)` the first time and then use `Union` for the others:

```
Public Function SMA(ByVal rng As Range, ByVal N As Long) As Variant
    Dim oRng As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            If oRng Is Nothing Then
                Set oRng = cell.Resize(N, 1)
            Else
                Set oRng = Application.Union(oRng, cell.Resize(N, 1))
            End If
    Next cell

    SMA = Application.Average(oRng)

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Yep, I thought about `Reisize` not working... +1 for posting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Average Non-Contiguous (UDF or not)

[image]

- Note that `Average` will fail if error values.

**Columns**

```vb
Function SMA_Columns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal RowsCount As Long = 1) _
As Double

    Dim urg As Range ' Combined (Union) Range
    Dim crg As Range ' Column Range

    For Each crg In FirstRowRange.Resize(RowsCount).Columns
        If Not IsEmpty(crg.Cells(1)) Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = crg Else Set urg = Union(urg, crg)
        End If
    Next crg
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    SMA_Columns = Application.Average(urg)

End Function
```

**Rows**

```vb
Function SMA_Rows( _
    ByVal FirstColumnRange As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnsCount As Long = 1) _
As Double

    Dim urg As Range ' Combined (Union) Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Row Range

    For Each rrg In FirstColumnRange.Resize(, ColumnsCount).Rows
        If Not IsEmpty(rrg.Cells(1)) Then
            If urg Is Nothing Then Set urg = rrg Else Set urg = Union(urg, rrg)
        End If
    Next rrg
    If urg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    SMA_Rows = Application.Average(urg)

End Function
```